# Laravel 5.2 shows apache screen instead of index.php

Tags: apache, laravel-5, httpd.conf, digital-ocean, centos7

I checked most of question regarding to my problems as this seems to be very common error for Laravel beginners but I can't find the solutions so far :(

I use the digital ocean VPN, centos7, php5.6, apache, windows 10.

Installed laravel and configured **httpd.conf**, **mysite.com.conf**, **.htaccess** and **hosts** fies then restart apache but still welcome screen doesn't show and it shows apache screen instead.

+==================================================+

here is my settings...

1) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None (default setting)
```

And added below the end of the file

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

For reference, other default settings are below

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2) /etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_access_log combined
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public_html>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3) /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
　<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
　　Options -MultiViews
　</IfModule>
　RewriteEngine On
　RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
　RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
　RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
　RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

4) C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
digitaloceanDropletIp mysite.com
```

5) publi_html folder img

[image]

I would be really appreciated if someone can tell me what is wrong my settings.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in this `<Directory "/var/www/html">` change `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jaysingkar, I just tried it but still showing apache screen :(

Comment: @hasmai did you restart apache2 afterwards?

Comment: Hi @jrenk, yes I did 'sudo apachectl restart' and 'sudo service httpd restart' both incase. But no luck :(

Comment: @jaysingkar, just wondered I overwrite '/var/www/html' to /var/www/mysite.com/public_html' but should I still need to keep '/var/www/html' as well? or not not not necessary?

Comment: @hasmai not needed

Comment: @jaysingkar ok, thanks for letting me know :) But still show apache :(

Comment: @hasmai I'm just wondering if this is just a typing mistake ?  /var/www/mysite.com/**publi_html**/.htaccess or it is supposed to be public

Comment: I mean, can you confirm directory name once

Comment: @jaysingkar, soz it was typo! the directory is : **/var/www/mysite.com/public_html**

Comment: @jaysingkar, I want to inform you just incase. in public_html folder there is No index.php

Comment: then what is it supposed to display ?

Comment: @jaysingkar, I thought welcome.blade.php?! No?

Comment: it must include index.php file

Comment: so that it can be redirect to your laravel application

Comment: If you check your default laravel installation, It would include the index.php file in public folder

Comment: @jaysingkar, thanks for your kind help. I installed laravel with composer and there is no index.php from the first :( And Laravel welcome showed it on local server that's why I thought I didn't need to create index.php. I just created empty index.php in public_html and it shows totally white blank page. Will google it how to fix. But thanks for being very patient!

Comment: Show your public_html folder

Comment: @KmasterYC, just added the image to 5). Thanks for your help!

Comment: replace this "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html"  to "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/public"

Comment: in your configuration

Comment: if you check the "public" directory you will get index.php there

Comment: @jaysingkar, cheers for your big help. Finally found the solution :) Will update here soon! Again thanks!

Comment: @RadLexus done it and cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
```

**To**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/public
```

Then restart your apache

Comment: thanks you so much for the help. Your answer was really helpful and finally Laravel logo came up :) I will update the solution here soon. Again thanks you! I dont have reputation more than 15 so my vote doesnt show up :(

Answer (score 1):

[Solution]

By kindest people's help, I finally managed to show Laravel logo! Stupidly I didn't realised index.php is in public folder!

I kept httpd.conf and hosts as same as above, but changed mysite.com.conf below and completely removed/deleted public_html/.htaccess (I may need it future but this stage I don't need).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/public"
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_access_log combined
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 <Directory "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/public">
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After this change, 403 Error came up (seems to be this happens for apache) so I added the below line just before 'RewriteEngine On' in public/.htaccess Refer: non English website

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Then 500 Error came up, so I used putty for the blow command (I had to do this even thought I previously did 'chmod 777 storage') Refere: Laravel blank white screen.

```
chmod -R guo+w storage
```

Then finally 'Laravel' showed up :) Anyway thanks for all help!